# useState() in react and typescript lose data in functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, typescript2.0

I have a problem with hook useState in reacjs and typescript, my problem is when I try load data in a useState and retrieve that data, lose that data, exemple below.

```
import React from 'react'
import {Row, Col} from 'react-styled-flexboxgrid'
import {Table, Th, Td, Done, Err} from './styles'
import {CampaingHeader, CampaingBody} from '../../../../../userCampaings'

const FormPreview: React.FC = () => {
   let token = window.sessionStorage.getItem('token')
   let CamHeader = new CampaingHeader(token)
   let CamBody = new CampaingBody(token)
   const [datach, setDatach] = React.useState(0)
   const [cpb, setCpb] = React.useState()

const getLast = () => {
    CamHeader.getLastCampaingHeader() // THIS IS MY API, AND RETURN ALL DATA I NEED
        .then(resp => {
            //console.info(resp.data.data.id) // IF I UNCOMMENT SHOW ME ALL MY DATA
            setDatach(resp.data.data.id) // THE PROBLEM IS HERE NOT ASSIGN MY DATA
        }).catch(err =>{
            console.error(err)
        })
}

const retrieveCampBody = () =>{
    // HERE IS MY ANOTHER API, USING "datach", BUT IS ZERO 
    // IF I PUT INSTED "datach" A NUMBER LIKE "3" THAT EXIST IN MY DATA BASE
    // RETRIEVE DATA.
    CamBody.getRetrieveCBody(datach)  
        .then(resp =>{
            console.info(resp.data.data)
            setCpb(resp.data.data) // OBVIOUSLY I CAN'T LOAD DATA HERE 
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.info(err)
        })
}

React.useEffect(()=>{
    getLast()
    console.info(datach) // CALLING DIRECTLY AND THE SAMETHING PROBLEM IS ZERO
    retrieveCampBody()
},[])

return(
    <div>
        //AND HERE NOT LOAD DATA BECOUSE, THE useState NOT WORKING WELL.
    </div>
)
}

export default FormPreview
```

could you tell me why useState lose my data, and how to solve that problem.

please..!

best words everyone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)? If anything it should help you understand the asynchronous nature of react state updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first request has likely not completed by the time the second one runs. So, `setDatach(resp.data.data.id)` has not set the value by the time `retrieveCampBody` runs. The value is still set to the default 0 value. You might try something along these lines:

```
  useEffect(() => {
   if (datach !== 0) {
    console.log(datach);
    retrieveCampBody();
    }
   }, [datach]);
```

Also, when you're calling data asynchronously from within `useEffect` the best way would be to do something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Create an scoped async function within useEffect
    async function getLastData() {
      await getLast();
    }    // Execute the created function from within useEffect
    getLastData(); 
}
```

Doing it this way will prevent `useEffect` from returning anything

Answer (score 2):

`getLast` runs asynchronusly. The data has not been populated by the time `retrieveCampBody` runs.

Call `getRetrieveCBody` only once `datach` has been assigned, in a separate effect hook:

```
React.useEffect(getLast, []);
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (datach) {
    retrieveCampBody();
  }
}, [datach]);
```

If the `datach` happens to only be used in `retrieveCampBody`, you could remove the `datach` from state entirely, and put the body of `retrieveCampBody`'s function inside `getLast`.